# Overriding anchor styling in an anchored container

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, dhtml

asp.net panel inhereting anchor style for the elements inside,
I want it not to inherit the style, just want the whole area of panel to be hyperlinked to a page

```
<a class="click" href="test.aspx">
<asp:Panel ID="pnBeta" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <div class="cake">
        <h2 class="choc">
        </h2>
    <ul class="Info">
        <li><span>test1:</span><asp:Label style="float:right;padding-right:5px" runat="server" ID="lblTest1"></asp:Label></li>
        <li><span>test2:</span><asp:Label style="float:right;padding-right:5px" runat="server" ID="lblTest2"></asp:Label></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a style to the panel like so: I added a few elements around the panel for testing and have included the markup here. Notice **class="PanelLink"**

```
<a href="test.aspx">No class</a><br/><a class="click" href="test.aspx">click class</a> 
<a class="click" href="test.aspx">
<asp:Panel class="PanelLink" ID="pnBeta" runat="server" Visible="false">
<div class="cake">
    <h2 class="choc">
    </h2>
<ul class="Info">
    <li><span>test1:</span><asp:Label style="float:right;padding-right:5px" runat="server" ID="lblTest1"></asp:Label></li>
    <li><span>test2:</span><asp:Label style="float:right;padding-right:5px" runat="server" ID="lblTest2"></asp:Label></li>
</ul>
<hr><br><br><br><br><hr>

</div>
</asp:Panel>
</a>
```

Add a style.  I added an anchor style to insure there was a style to overcome. The seperate .click style is the key in my testing.

```
a {
    color:#008800;
    text-decoration:underline;
  }

.click {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#00F;
}
.PanelLink {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    cursor:hand;
}
```

Entire panel *IS* the link and the rendered text does not have the underlines. 
[image]

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/mLHd3/ Base set to show solution.

Comment: I tried that, but somehow its still underlined...tried on panel as well as individual spans...makes me wonder why is it not overriding the style

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to try to duplicate your issue. I believe I have. I get the text color correct but the underline decoration remains. Working on it.

Comment: @sam Updated the answer and the fiddle with the solution that worked in my testing.